# Compiler Error:Invalid Type

Tags: apex

I am writing test class for this Class

```
public class ScenarioDumpJob {
    public class ArrayOf_xsd_string {
         //Some code
    }
    public class runJobReturn_element {
         //Some code
    }
    public class args_element {
         //Some code
    }
    public class ScenarioDump2_Copy {
         //Some code
        public  List<String> runJob(String[] item) {
            ScenarioDumpJob.args_element request_x = new ScenarioDumpJob.args_element();
            request_x.item = item;
             //Some code
        }
    }
}
```

My test Class is

```
@IsTest
private Class ScenarioDumpJobTest{
    private static testMethod void ArrayOf_xsd_stringTest(){
        new ScenarioDumpJob.ArrayOf_xsd_string();
    }
    private static testMethod void runJobReturn_elementTest(){
        new ScenarioDumpJob.runJobReturn_element();
    }
    private static testMethod void args_elementTest(){
        new ScenarioDumpJob.args_element();
    }
    private static testMethod void ScenarioDump2_CopyTest(){
        new ScenarioDumpJob.ScenarioDump2_Copy();
    }
    private static testMethod void ScenarioDump2_CopyCoverMethodTest(){
        String[] item = new String[]{'item','0','-1','false'};
        List<String> lst = new List<String>();
        lst.add(new ScenarioDumpJob.ScenarioDump2_Copy.runJob(item));
    }

    //Web Service Mock
    private class WebServiceMockImpl implements WebServiceMock
    {
        public void doInvoke(
            Object stub, Object request, Map<String, Object> response,
            String endpoint, String soapAction, String requestName,
            String responseNS, String responseName, String responseType)
        {
            if(request instanceof ScenarioDumpJob.args_element)
                response.put('response_x', new ScenarioDumpJob.args_element());
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

When I am trying to save it is giving me error:

> Compile Error: Invalid type: ScenarioDumpJob.ScenarioDump2_Copy.runJob
>   at line 17 column 21

Please let me know where I am making mistake.

Comment: share the ScenarioDumpJob class code

Comment: Try `ScenarioDump2_Copy.ScenarioDumpJob.runJob()`

Comment: I have updated my code.

Comment: Can you try updating this line 
lst.add(new ScenarioDumpJob.ScenarioDump2_Copy.runJob(item));
to
lst.add(new ScenarioDumpJob.ScenarioDump2_Copy().runJob(item));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`runJob(String[] item)` is not a static method. So you cannot call using class name. You need to create an instance and then invoke method using that instance.

```
String[] item = new String[]{'item','0','-1','false'};
List<String> lst = new List<String>();
//Instance of ScenarioDump2_Copy inner class 
ScenarioDumpJob.ScenarioDump2_Copy dumb2 = new ScenarioDumpJob.ScenarioDump2_Copy();
lst.add(dumb2.runJob(item));
```

More on [static and instance methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm).

Answer (score -1):

runJob() method from ScenarioDump2_Copy class accepts argument of array of String (String[] item).

So you just need to pass the array of String while calling this method

```
lst.add(new ScenarioDumpJob.ScenarioDump2_Copy().runJob(YourArrayOfString));
```

Comment: I updated the code by adding array of string. But still I am getting same error

Comment: put system.debug('****What is Returning****'+ScenarioDumpJob.ScenarioDump2_Copy.runJob(item));
and check what you are getting in return and also check the return type

Comment: Can you try updating this line lst.add(new ScenarioDumpJob.ScenarioDump2_Copy.runJob(item)); to lst.add(new ScenarioDumpJob.ScenarioDump2_Copy().runJob(item));

Comment: Great, good to see your issue is resolved.